# Need to render an HTML page into a Bootstrap modal ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using razor view, and looking to render a raw HTML page into a  partial view, and then return that view into a modal. It is returning the error code : 
System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view 'SampleSlide' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">
    <span class="close" style="color:white">×</span>
    @Html.Partial("SampleSlide")
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal3');
var img3 = document.getElementById('myImg3');
var modalImg3 = document.getElementById("img03");
img3.onclick = function () {
    modal3.style.display = "block";
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal3.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: The View SampleSlide must be in the same folder as the current view you have this code in.

Comment: @Dobbins Hello and thank you for your response. I attempted your answer, but it did not yield results. The slide has several dependencies that go along with it inside of a folder "demo slide" should I call the full path inside my partial?

Comment: Or just create A controller with the Same Name as the Folder that holds the slides and Create an action on that controller that returns the SampleSlideView.       Use @Html.Action("Controller","Action")

Comment: Provide the full path for partial view. like (`@Html.Partial("~/ProjectName/Veiws/FolderName/SampleSlide.cshtml")`)

Comment: @mmushtaq Will this work with a pure HTML file? This is not a cshtml file, it is a generated file from Captivate 9

Comment: Not sure about that. Just give it a try.

Comment: @mmushtaq Negative result, returned error  System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view '~/Training/DemoSlide/SampleSlide.html' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Training/DemoSlide/SampleSlide.html

Comment: try this one `@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Training/DemoSlide/SampleSlide.html")))` instead of `Html.Partial(....)`

Comment: @mmushtaq Returned error  System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Stephanie\Documents\GitHub\DODMOU\DODMOU.UI\Training\DemoSl‌ide\SampleSlide.html‌​'.It seems that I am getting closer, I will check the file path and ensure it is correct

Comment: Your html page is present at this location?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130242/discussion-between-joshua-and-mmushtaq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into a html page i create  this div.

```
        <div class="modal-body" id="contenedor">
        </div>
```

In this page add the script.

```
$('#windowsEncuesta').modal('show');
    var contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");
    var html;
    debugger;
    var url = '/Event/ControlPreguntas';
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        html = data;
        contenedor.innerHTML = html;
    });
```

I used one controller(Event) and antion ControlPreguntas it retun a PartialView. So you can show it with innerHTML.

Comment: Please give an explanation with your answer to make it more complete.